# SQL Server Fast Way to Determine IF Exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I need to find a fast way to determine if records exist in a database table.  The normal method of IF Exists (condition) is not fast enough for my needs.  I've found something that is faster but does not work quite as intended.

The normal IF Exists (condition) which works but is too slow for my needs:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
           From dbo.SecurityPriceHistory
           Where  FortLabel = 'EP'
           and    TradeTime >= '2020-03-20 15:03:53.000'
           and    Price >= 2345.26)
```

My work around that doesn't work, but is extremely fast:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT IIF(COUNT(*) = 0, null, 1)   
           From   dbo.SecurityPriceHistory
           Where  FortLabel = 'EP'
           and    TradeTime >= '2020-03-20 15:03:53.000'
           and    Price >= 2345.26)
```

The issue with the second solution is that when the count(*) = 0, null is returned, but that causes IF EXISTS(null) to return true.

The second solution is fast because it doesn't read any data in the execution plan, while the first one does read data.

Comment: I don't see how `count(*)` could be faster than the `exists` query -- Unless SQL Server is smart enough to know that an aggregation query with no `GROUP BY` or `HAVING` always returns one row, so `EXISTS` is always true.

Comment: This must be the case, IIF always return one row, so it can optimize the actual reading of data.

Comment: . . `IIF()` has nothing to do with it.  It is the `COUNT(*)` that returns one row.

Comment: Under different conditions, the select returns either 1 or NULL as a resultset.  Unfortunately, the NULL resultset EXISTS.

Answer (score 1):

I suggested leaving the original code unchanged, but adding an index to cover one (or more) of the columns in the `WHERE` clause.

If I changed anything, I might limit the `SELECT` clause to a single non-null small column.

Comment: There is an index on the columns in the where clause.  The execution plan shows that an index seek is being used.  Selecting a single column does not change the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Switching to a column store index in my particular use case appears to solve my performance problem.

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
           From dbo.SecurityPriceHistory
           Where  FortLabel = 'EP' and
                  TradeTime >= '2020-03-20 15:03:53.000' and
                  Price >= 2345.26
          )
```

You either want an index on:

- `SecurityPriceHistory(Fortlabel, TradeTime, Price)`
- `SecurityPriceHistory(Fortlabel, Price, TradeTime)`

The difference is whether `TradeTime` or `Price` is more selective.  A single column index is probably not sufficient for this query.

The third column in the index is just there so the index covers the query and doesn't have to reference the data pages.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

IF (select count(*) From   dbo.SecurityPriceHistory
Where  FortLabel = 'EP' and TradeTime >= '2020-03-20 15:03:53.000' and Price >= 2345.26) > 0
begin
---your update statement
end